Error C6011:Dereferencing NULL pointer 'NAME'. C
I'm getting the warning in the title in my C program, referring to the variable "sequence" in the first for loop.
Can someone help me figure out what it means and how to fix it?
This is the code (minus the headers):
int main()
{

    int* sequence;
    int sequenceSize = 10;
    sequence = (int*)malloc(sequenceSize*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < sequenceSize; i++)
    {
        sequence[i] = i * 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sequenceSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", sequence[i]);
    }

    free(sequence);
    return 0;
}


Welcome! Pasting that into a main() (with stdio.h and stdlib.h) gives no compiler warnings and no execution errors. Can you please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

You also say "a warning" but the title says "error". Please also post the exact message.

Related: What does "C6011 dereferencing null pointer" mean in my program?

You've not checked that the memory allocation was successful, and malloc() could (but probably won't) return NULL, and then you'd be dereferencing a null pointer in the loops.  So, if you do as your textbook tells you to do and check the return value from malloc(), you can probably avoid the error.
If your textbook didn't say something similar to "Always check the return value from malloc() and its friends", then you should forcibly throw your textbook into a furnace where it can no longer mislead you or anyone else.
Note that a simple Google search using c6011finds Warning C6011 and the description starts:

This warning indicates that your code dereferences a potentially null pointer. If the pointer value is invalid, the result is undefined. To resolve the issue, validate the pointer before use.


The significant word is "potentially". The helpful compiler knows you haven't validated the memory allocation (mine didn't).

There is Microsoft's Warning C6011 but my MSVC compilation didn't issue it.

Interesting that your MSVC compilation didn't give the warning.  I expect you need to enable it like you need to enable fussier warnings with GCC et al.  If was reported as an error, that probably requires another option to convert warnings into errors.  It is good that the OP is using such fussy options — it will improve the quality of their code as they learn to use the information that the compiler provides.  The OP also needs to learn how to use Google (or any other search engine of their choice) to find information.

Even with -Wall there is no C6011 (MSVC 2022) mentioned.

Poking around a bit harder, I found Code analysis for C/C++ overview.  It seems to indicate that you need to add a /analyze option to the command line.  It's also a pity that MS uses the term "C/C++".  It is a nuisance because here on SO we spend time trying to disabuse people of the notion that C and C++ are the same language.

I use the command line, perhaps VS Studio or VS Code are more rigorous. P.S. Ah yes, adding /analyze produces the warning. I've added that to my batch file (I don't invoke CL or NMAKE directly :)
